# acro plural with changing first word not last

Tags: acro

In the normal text I want to see:

> Europäischen Organisation für Kernforschung (CERN)

and in the list of abbreviations I want to have:

> **CERN**  Europäische Organisation für Kernforschung

So in my text I need the "n" at the end of the first word. How can I do this with acro package? I tried it with some plural, but didn't get it soo far.

Comment: Specify the `long-plural-form` property

Comment: exactly what i needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @cgnieder the answer is using:

```
long-plural-form
```